# Server requires reboot after modifying the interface configuration file

Tags: networking, configuration, alma-linux

I modified the interface configuration file as follows:

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens160
```

I have changed the IP and gateway. I run the command as follows:

```
nmcli connection down ens160 && nmcli connection up ens160
```

However, the IP address does not change when I do ifconfig. I have to reboot the server for the change to take place.

What other commands can I run so I won't have to reboot the server? I am running AlmaLinux 8.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After editing the interface configuration file, you should run:

```
nmcli connection reload
```

Alternatively, you should make your modifications to the interface configuration with

```
nmcli connection modify ens160 ...
```

or

```
nmcli connection edit ens160
```

or

```
nmtui
```

or with any other NetworkManager front-end.

If you make your changes in one of these ways, the "RedHat-like" NetworkManager configuration backend will automatically update the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*` files appropriately, as that backend is read/write.

(On Debian and related distributions, the NetworkManager backend that reads Debian's classic `/etc/network/interfaces` is read-only, and any configuration updates get stored to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` or to a per-user location which may be specific to distribution and/or desktop-environment used.)

Comment: It seems NetworkManager does not monitor changes to the configuration file. When editing the configuration file, both ```nmcli connection reload``` and ```nmcli connection up ens160``` does not work. ```nmcli connection up ens160``` works for ```nmcli connection edit ens160```, ```nmcli connection modify ens160``` and ```nmtui```.